# Java & Kafka: Connection to node 999 could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml is

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  pg-master:
    image: postgres-9.6:3
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    environment:
     - VIRTUAL_HOST=postgres.local
  web:
    build: .
    links:
      - pg-master:postgres.local
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
  zookeeper:
    image: jplock/zookeeper:3.4.6
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.0
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=TestTopic1:3:1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=999
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

In web docker container, the java kafka producer:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 0);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
this.kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
```

But, I got `[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-2] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

NO idea why. any suggestions welcomed. Thanks very much.

**UPDATE**

I can produce and consume messages by `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic TestTopic1 --from-beginning` and `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic TestTopic1` inside and outside kafka docker container.

what is `localhost` inside docker container?

**UPDATE**

Now, I changed the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` and `bootstrap.servers` of Kafka Java producer config manually to the docker host ip (got by `ifconfig`).
Now, it is working. Now, I have no idea how to get docker host ip and set it in docker-compose files automatically by program or bash.

Comment: I ran a docker-compose with the zookeper & kafka config you have used. I only changed KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME to the docker IP. I can run a KafkaProducer (your code) to send messages to Kakfa without error. This may be because Kafka broker has not started. Check the docker-compose logs to see if the Kafka broker has started without error.

Comment: @ShankarPS kafka is up. it seems that my java program cannot access zookeeper and kafka from inside docker container. Java program is running in docker container.

Comment: try after modifying KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME in docker-compose.yml to match your docker host IP.

Comment: @ShankarPS what is docker host ip?

Comment: Run this command in the Docker terminal- $docker-machine ip

Comment: I believe the IP you are looking for is the docker bridge IP, usually starts with 172. By default containers can communicate over that IP

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolve this issue by copying `/etc/hosts` from the host to the Docker container. Apparently Kubernetes DNS [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) were not correctly working on our setup.