# set docker host ip (advertised.host.name) for mac and ubuntu in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have a web application running in docker container, and a kafka broker running in another docker container. I am using docker-compose to setup up the docker containers. but I found that it is a little difficult to config the networking for docker containers. so, I posted some questions: [Java & Kafka: Connection to node 999 could not be established. Broker may not be available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450270/java-kafka-connection-to-node-999-could-not-be-established-broker-may-not-be)

I got some hits to setup `advertised.host.name` the from here [Cannot produce message to kafka from service running in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716065/cannot-produce-message-to-kafka-from-service-running-in-docker). Now, my web application can produce the messages to the kafka docker container. But I got another issue: I can get docker host ip by `ifconfig docker0`, and hardcoded it in docker-compose.yml. I have no idea how to get it in mac. Our docker-compose files are for dev, and they should be run in lots of developers' computers. **so, we need some reliable way to get the ip automatically and dynamically by some programs.**

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Why can't you just `-p 9092:9092` on the Mac? The only reliable way to get a port mapped to an external network (on a Mac) is to use Docker Machine

Comment: @cricket_007, I do not know how to set host ip in docker-compose.yml. port 9092 is working fine.

Comment: Also, not clear why you're setting that property https://stackoverflow.com/a/37844327/2308683

Comment: Docker Compose can accept environmental variables... `${HOST_IP}`, but again, not sure why you need it. You can have the container listening on `0.0.0.0`, then you forward the Mac port to the container

Comment: You might be interested in this example https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/4.0.x/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

For clients connecting to any Kafka node, Kafka will answer back which hostname to connect too. If you run a Kafka node a docker-compose environment and connect from 'outside' docker - which is typically when doing development that hostname might be incorrect.

If that's the problem, you could solve it by using the following environment for kafka:

```
kafka:
  image: <my kafka image>
  ports:
  - 9094:9094
  links:
  - zookeeper
  environment:
    - "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME}"
    - "ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181"
    - "KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME}:9094"
    - "KAFKA_LISTENERS=INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094"
    - "KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT"
    - "KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INSIDE"
```

and also set environment variable KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME to the hostname of your laptop.

Then you can connect to the kafka that's running your docker environment by using the address **localhost:9094**
Any application that's running inside the same docker environment can connect using the internal networking to **kafka:9092**

On Windows and MacOs you might have some internal environment variable like HOST_IP or HOSTNAME that's already configured, but to avoid hassle I'd configure KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME in my default environment anyway to my laptop's hostname.

Comment: Would this be effectively the same as specifying a `hostname: ${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME}` field in the docker compose file above? Struggling to find the difference between the `hostname` parameter and environment variable used here.

Comment: Afaik that wouldn't be the same. KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME is a setting for kafka, which hostname the listeners return when an client connect.